# SQL DB2 display the rows of data where the Name Field Changes

Tags: sql, db2

I have a dataset containing multiple fields but the main 3 I am concerned with are Client, Name and Date. I need to select the rows where the name changes. I was trying to use Partition By but it didn’t work for me.

Client_Info Table

```
Client  Name    Date
1   John    12-jun-2023
1   John    13-jun-2023
1   Mick    14-jun-2023
1   Mick    15-jun-2023
1   Paddy   16-jun-2023
2   Mary    12-jun-2023
2   Mary    13-jun-2023
2   Mary    14-jun-2023
2   Paula   15-jun-2023
2   Rita    16-jun-2023
```

SQL tried

```
Select * from client_Info CI1
Inner join (select row_number() over (partition by client order by date desc) rn,
client,name,date 
from Client_Info) CI2
on (CI2.client = CI1.client and
CI2.Date < CI1.Date and 
CI2.Name <> CI1.Name)
Where rn = 1
Order by CI1.Date;
```

Results should be:

```
Client  Name    Date
1   John    12-jun-2023
1   Mick    14-jun-2023
1   Paddy   16-jun-2023
2   Mary    12-jun-2023
2   Paula   15-jun-2023
2   Rita    16-jun-2023
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [lag](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=expressions-olap-specification#sdx-synid_lag-function) olap function.

```
with client_info (Client, Name, Date) as
(
values
  (1, 'John ', '12-jun-2023')
, (1, 'John ', '13-jun-2023')
, (1, 'Mick ', '14-jun-2023')
, (1, 'Mick ', '15-jun-2023')
, (1, 'Paddy', '16-jun-2023')
, (2, 'Mary ', '12-jun-2023')
, (2, 'Mary ', '13-jun-2023')
, (2, 'Mary ', '14-jun-2023')
, (2, 'Paula', '15-jun-2023')
, (2, 'Rita ', '16-jun-2023')
)
select Client, Name, Date
from
(
select 
  *
, coalesce (lag (Name) over (partition by Client order by Date), '')
  as Name_prev
from client_info
)
where Name <> Name_prev
```

| CLIENT | NAME | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 12-jun-2023 |
| 1 | Mick | 14-jun-2023 |
| 1 | Paddy | 16-jun-2023 |
| 2 | Mary | 12-jun-2023 |
| 2 | Paula | 15-jun-2023 |
| 2 | Rita | 16-jun-2023 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/C5Y7eBTe)